# How to route gRPC in Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, istio

I'm new with service mesh thing, so I did some PoC of basic implementation of microservices in kubernetes with istio.

I have 2 Deployments which is supposed to be talking to each other using gRPC. When I call the grpc server it returned error `rpc error: code = Internal desc = server closed the stream without sending trailers`

This is my grpc Service config:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpcserver
  labels:
    app: grpcserver
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
  selector:
    app: grpcserver`

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Istio [docs](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/),

> Service ports must be named. The port names must be of the form {protocol}[-{suffix}] with http, http2, grpc, mongo, or redis as the  in order to take advantage of Istio’s routing features.

So the Service configuration should be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpcserver
  labels:
    app: grpcserver
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: grpc
  selector:
    app: grpcserver
```